# Issue in the top down approach to the Coin Change (Similar to the 0-1 backpack problem)

Tags: python, dynamic-programming, topdown

I am now working on the Leetcode 322. Coin Change, the question is as following:

> You are given an integer array coins representing coins of different
> denominations and an integer amount representing a total amount of
> money.
>
> Return the fewest number of coins that you need to make up that
> amount. If that amount of money cannot be made up by any combination
> of the coins, return -1.
>
> You may assume that you have an infinite number of each kind of coin.
>
> Example 1:
>
> Input: coins = [1,2,5], amount = 11 Output: 3 Explanation: 11 = 5 + 5 + 1
>
> Example 2:
>
> Input: coins = [2], amount = 3 Output: -1
>
> Example 3:
>
> Input: coins = [1], amount = 0 Output: 0
>
> Example 4:
>
> Input: coins = [1], amount = 1 Output: 1
>
> Example 5:
>
> Input: coins = [1], amount = 2 Output: 2

I tried to solve it via the top-down DP with memorization. I set a parameter in the helper function to remember the count.

```
class Solution:
    def coinChange(self, coins: List[int], amount: int) -> int:
        c = set(coins)
        dp = [0] * (amount + 1)

        def helper(a, count):
            if a == 0:
                return count
            # if a in c:
            #    return 1 + count
            if dp[a] != 0:
                return dp[a]
            res = math.inf
            for coin in c:
                if a - coin >= 0 and helper(a-coin, count+1) != -1:  
                    res = min(res, helper(a-coin, count+1))
            dp[a] = res if res < math.inf else -1
            return dp[a]

        return helper(amount, 0)
```

But it won't pass the case as:

> [1,2,5]
> 100

The result supposes to be 20, but I got 92.

I tried to figure it out the whole afternoon, but not sure where I did wrong. I hope you can give me some suggestion where I went wrong.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**!!! THIS IS A COMPLETE SOLUTION !!!**

Ok, so here is my solution to this problem (idea explained below):

```py
def solve(lst, amount):
    lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x, reverse=True)
    cases = []
    for seq in [lst[i:] for i in range(len(lst))]:
        current_amount = 0
        count = 0
        for item in seq:
            while True:
                if current_amount + item == amount:
                    count += 1
                    current_amount += item
                    break
                elif current_amount + item > amount:
                    break
                elif current_amount < amount:
                    count += 1
                    current_amount += item
            if current_amount == amount:
                break

        if current_amount == amount:
            cases.append(count)

    if cases:
        return min(cases)
    return -1


print(solve([1, 2, 5], 100))
print(solve([1, 5, 7, 9], 12))

# 20
# 2
```

Explanation:

**!!! MAIN IDEA

First You have to start with the largest number in the list because it takes the least amount of additions to come the closest or completely become the final amount.
!!!**

**EDIT**
As suggested by @nitinkumarp in comments, previous version (can check edits but why?) failed in some cases as mentioned in the comment, a workaround for that issue is to check all sequences in order, still using the greedy approach but slicing the original list shorter and shorter so that it can also check the correct solution which is 7 + 5, which is 2 coins.

So first thing to do is sort the list from the largest to the smallest number as shown with `.sort()` function.

Then for each number in that list (for loop starts with the first item in the list so the largest number) put them in a while True loop so that they keep adding to the total until condition is met:

There are 3 conditions:

1. current amount (from all the additions) plus the current item in the list equals the final amount, in that case increase the count by one and add the current item to total and then break out of the loop
2. if the current amount + current item in list are bigger than the final amount just break out (this makes sure that no more of such number are added)
3. the one that will get used the most is the one that checks if the current amount is smaller than the final one, but it is important that they are `elif` statements because in that case if one statement turns out to be true it doesn't check the rest which is not needed in this case because otherwise it would turn out to be true even if You couldn't add more to the current amount to not exceed the final amount.
4. this if statement is outside of the `while True` loop and checks if the final amount is matched when a number 'breaks out' of the `while True` loop, this is to prevent continuous checking even tho the result would be already achieved.

Then the result get evaluated and if the current amount doesn't match the final print -1 else print the count

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is quite impressive. I am wondering if you can point out where I did wrong in my approach? I got so confusing.

Comment: @QiangSuper interesting, You use recursion so it may be sort of hard to track what actually happens but as I said You have to start with the largest number............... Honestly looking at Your solution it is quite hard to track all the recursions, so I can't really tell You (yet) where exactly You went wrong, the only thing I can suggest is starting with the largest number (try that and maybe that will solve the issue)

Comment: I see. Thanks for your suggestion. I will try to modify my code based on your suggestions.

Comment: Recently I was asked same question in my interview and I had solved it with same technique i.e. using largest denomination first to reach as near as possible to the amount and traverse through all denomination until amount gets 0. It passed all test and hidden test of site but the interviewer showed me the input where this (greedy) approach fails. `[1, 5, 7, 9] amt=12`. Actual answer is 2 but greedy approach gives output as 4.

Comment: @nitinkumarp hmm, yes, just checked, as it seems to me, the greedy approach would still work, if only you wouldn't stop the function once it reaches the target amount, if you were to test for a each sequence like this: `[9, 7, 5, 1]`, `[7, 5, 1]`, `[5, 1]`, `[1]` and then compare results from each of those cases, it should work, granted it would be slower but unless that coin list is huuuge, it wouldn't really matter

Comment: @nitinkumarp edited answer to solve that problem, thanks a lot for mentioning it

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution.
The main idea is to make use of the max value element in the list as much as possible and when it becomes dysfunctional, it is about to remove it from the list and use the new max value element.

```
class Solution:
    def coinChange(self, coins, amount):
        result = []
        new_amount = amount
        while len(coins) > 0:
            while new_amount >= max(coins):
                new_amount -= max(coins)
                result.append(max(coins))
            coins.remove(max(coins))
        if len(result) == 0:
            return 0
        if sum(result) != amount:
            return -1
        return len(result)
```

Let's test the results;

```
coins = [2, 5, 4, 1]
amount = 10

s = Solution()
print(s.coinChange(coins=coins, amount=amount))
```

Output: 2

Because it produced a result list like this; [5, 5]